# How to use command to switch to Terminal-Normal mode?

Tags: function, vim, terminal, mode

I would like to make a key mapping which could move to terminal window and switch to Terminal-Normal mode, and perform the opposite action again to look over the long message.

```
map <F4> call Toggle_Terminal_Mode()<cr>

function Toggle_Terminal_Mode()
  if &buftype ==""
    move to terminal-window         
    switch terminal-normal mode     " ?????
    do blah blah blah....       
    
  elseif &buftype=="terminal" && mode()=="n"
    swich terminal-mode           
    move back to edited buffer window       
  endif
endfunc
```

I know I can use `<C-w>N` or `<C-\><C-n>` to switch to Terminal-Normal mode, but I want to use command instead in function so as to do other thing.

And I try

1. :execute "normal `\<C-w>N`" doesn't work,
   and `<C-\><C-N>` either.
2. :call term_sendkey(..) , does't work.

How to use command to switch to terminal-Normal mode ?

Comment: Lookup `tnoremap` [here](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html)

Comment: @wxz I guess you mean that split the process between call function() and `<C-W>N` when mapping, so as to prevent the problem. That's a feasible method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I try the `<expr>` to solve the conditional requirement.

```
nnoremap <expr><F3> &bt=="" ? "<C-w>j<C-\><C-n>z100<CR>H" : "z10<cr>i" . "<C-_>k"
```

If current buffer type is "" (null), it will jump down to terminal window(default),
go to Normal mode, and resize line height to max size(supposed 100).To look the long message in terminal.

If current buffer type is "terminal", it will restore to 10 line height, go to terminal mode , and go back to the up window. To continue editing the code window.

But I am still finding the method how to change terminal mode in command (not key mapping method).